# Implicit conversion to Seq[T] from Array[T]

Tags: scala, types, implicit-conversion, implicit, view-bound

I'm having some trouble with view bounds. I have written the following function, which should take any object `seq` viewable as a `Seq[T]` and return `None` if it is empty, or `Some(seq)` otherwise.

```scala
def noneIfEmpty[T, S <% Seq[T]](seq: S): Option[S] =
  if (seq.isEmpty) None else Some(seq)
```

Let's define the function...

```scala
scala> def noneIfEmpty[T, S <% Seq[T]](seq: S): Option[S] = ...
noneIfEmpty: [T, S](seq: S)(implicit evidence$1: S => scala.collection.immutable.Seq[T])Option[S]
```

Okay, the function signature looks right. Let's try an empty list...

```scala
scala> noneIfEmpty(List())
res54: Option[List[Nothing]] = None
```

So far so good. Now let's try a nonempty list...

```scala
scala> noneIfEmpty(List(1,2,3))
res55: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Great. How about an Array?

```scala
scala> noneIfEmpty(Array())
<console>:15: error: No implicit view available from Array[Nothing] => scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Any].
              noneIfEmpty(Array())
                         ^
```

Not so great. What's going on here? Isn't there an implicit conversion from `Array[T]` to `WrappedArray[T]`? Shouldn't `scala.Predef.wrapRefArray` take care of this?

Comment: Works for me in 2.11.2 console.

Comment: Same here, what version of scala are you using?

Comment: It works when it's just `scala.collection.Seq`, but doesn't for `scala.collection.immutable.Seq` as in the original post. I don't think there's a view from `Array[T]` into `scala.collection.immutable.Seq[T]`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you have import `scala.collection.immutable.Seq` somewhere?

There are series implicit view named `*ArrayOps` defined in `scala.Predef` which convert `Array[T]` to `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps[T]`, but not `immutable.Seq`.

```
scala> def noneIfEmpty[S <% collection.Seq[_]](seq: S): Option[S] =
     |   if(seq.isEmpty) None else Some(seq)
noneIfEmpty: [S](seq: S)(implicit evidence$1: S => Seq[_])Option[S]

scala> noneIfEmpty(Array[Int]())
res0: Option[Array[Int]] = None

scala> noneIfEmpty(Array[Int](1, 2, 3))
res1: Option[Array[Int]] = Some([I@7c92fffb)
```